# C# converting Short utf8 sequence or malformed UTF8 using StreamReader.Read()

Tags: c#, utf-8, streamreader, converters

In C#, I am trying to convert contents of some file form UTF-8 to their equivalent of Int32, using [StreamReader.Read()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.read?view=netframework-4.8).

```
 sr = new StreamReader(inputStream, Encoding.UTF8);
 return sr.Read();
```

Some lines of the file might have short utf8 sequence or malformed UTF8. For example when I open one of the files in "Hex Editor Neo", I see the contents as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs9M8.png)

In this case, I get back -1 which is the documentation reads: "if no more characters are available". But the fact is, this is not a complete sequence of utf-8 to begin with.

Is there a way where I can distinguish if my input is malformed/short versus when there is no more characters available?

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean something like a NUL terminated string?

Comment: Please provide more information. See [mcve]

Comment: Thanks Barns, hope it's more clear now.

@Charles, basically I want to know if the contents have valid format, compliance with utf-8 specifications.

Comment: When `StreamReader.Read()` returns -1, it means that it couldn't decode the char in that position, but it will continue to decode other chars, if any, until it reaches the end of the stream. If you get -1 and `StreamReader.EndOfStream = false`, then you know you have malformed content or not all content is UTF8 encoded. You can append `(char)StreamReader.Read()` to a StringBuilder while the value is > 0 (but, it's not exactly clear what you want to do). If the file content is supposed to contain UTF8-encoded text, you may have malformed content if -1 is returned, at some point.

Comment: The `StreamReader.Read` method reads a single character and returns it as an Int32 (which I'm assuming represents a Unicode code point).  I don't understand your *"I am trying to convert contents of some file form UTF-8 to their equivalent of Int32"*. The code you show reads a single character, not a "file". Have you tried reading it in as a byte array and doing the conversion from there? No one is going to be able to help you unless you show more code and give a better/more consistent problem statement

Comment: How can UTF-8 be maliformed?  It is one byte and unsigned.  You shouldn't cast it to a signed int.  If you really want 32 bits than cast to uint.  The problem is cast character 0x80 to 0xFF you will get sign extension and get bad data like 0xFFFFFFB7.

Comment: @jdweng It's not UTF8 that *can be malformed*, it's the Text read by stream that can be. UTF8 is not 1 byte per char, it's 1 byte per char if the codepoint maps to a char in the ASCII table, otherwise is 2 or 3 bytes per char. Text corruption is not really that uncommon

Comment: @Jimi: What do you thing the 8 means in UTF-8???  Unicode is two bytes!!!

Comment: @jdweng  `8` in UTF8 means that each byte is represented by the full 8 bits (UTF8 means *8-bit Unicode Transformation Format*), not 7 as in other formats. UTF8 uses 1 to 4 bytes (1 if the char maps to a ASCII char, 4 only if a codepoint is mapped beyond `U+10000`). *Unicode is two bytes* doesn't mean anything. UTF8 is a Unicode format. You probably meant UTF16-LE, Windows standard encoding for strings, where each char is represented by two bytes, also in the ASCII realm.